# Testing if an object contains a given value

Tags: javascript, object

I have a function that accepts two args - an object, and a value. I want to check if the object contains the given value.

For example:

```
{a: "b", c: "d"}
```

Contains value `"d"` as key `c` stores it.

Comment: `Jim` isn’t an own property. Only `name` and `course` are, in this case. That’s what the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method is for.

Comment: *hasOwnProperty* tests if an object has a property, you're supposed to be testing values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the object and check if the value passed is in them using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var containsValue = function(val, obj){
  return Object.values(obj).includes(val);
};

console.log(containsValue("Jim", {name: "Jim", course: "FEDev"}));
console.log(containsValue("Jim", {name: "Nope", course: "FEDev"}));
```